# Conditional expectation proof.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I am reviewing in a book the proof of the following equation:

E(1<sub>A</sub> |{∅,B<sup>C</sup>,B,Ω})=P(A│B)1<sub>B</sub>+P(A│B<sup>C</sup> )1<sub>B<sup>C</sup></sub>

The proof begins by saying "Note that every measurable function with respect to the σ-algebra G (for E (X | G)) given by {∅,B<sup>C</sup>,B,Ω} is constant in both B<sup>C</sup> and B.

My question is: Why every measurable function with respect to the σ-algebra G is constant in both B<sup>C</sup> and B?

Comment: See   [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3641567/show-that-ex-mid-y-ex-mid-a-11-a-1-cdots-ex-mid-a-n1-a-n-when-si

Answer (score 1):

Let be measurable w.r.t $G$. If $f$ takes two distinct values $a,b$ on $B$  then $B\cap f^{-1} \{a\}$ and $B\cap f^{-1} \{b\}$ must both be in the given sigma algebra. These sets are non-empty,  disjoint and they are both contained in $B$. There are no such subsets of $B$ in the sigma algebra so $f$ cannot attain more than one value on $B$. Similarly for $B^{c}$.